# sharepoint 2010 Query data from database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

On the main page home.aspx, I would like to query some data from Oracle database.

I've carefully looked for a such option, but I cannot find anything releated to it.

Can someone please guide me?

Thank you.

Comment: Default page can be easily changed, so set it to your own web application page and I suppose that in the code behind your should be able to access the database as in a normal ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Oracle connector and register it as safe in the web.config of the SharePoint Web. Use it like any other sql connector but with OracleConnection as you should.

I myself would have chosen a bit different approach and developed a webpart instead. If you develop and deploy a webpart project in SharePoint 2010 any used modules should be properly registered automatically during the deployment. Start with webparts here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513148.aspx

And if you don't know what the above means you probably shouldn't mess with SharePoint that way! (Sorry but it's true)